# Error in creating a function for printing data of a linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I made a linked list using the following code.

```
# Node class
class Node:
  
    # Function to initialise the node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data # Assign data
        self.next = None # Initialize next as null
  
  
# Linked List the master class contains a Node object
class LinkedList:
  
    # Function to initialize head
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

And added values to it as:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
  
    # Start with the empty list
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.head = Node(1)
    llist.head.next = Node(2)
    llist.head.next.next = Node('3a')
```

Then I tried to make a function to print the data of the linkedlist as:

```
def printl(llist):
    temp = llist.head
    while(temp):
        return temp.data
        temp = temp.next
```

But it returned only the first value i.e 1. How can I print all the data present in the linked list?

Comment: `return temp.data` will cause the loop to end. Perhaps, you want to `print` it instead?

Comment: You can either do what @shahkalpesh suggested or use `yield` instead of return

Comment: print() worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Node class
class Node:
    # Function to initialise the node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data  # Assign data
        self.next = None  # Initialize next as null


# Linked List the master class contains a Node object
class LinkedList:
    # Function to initialize head
    def __init__(self):
        self.node = None

    def add_next_node(self, data):
        next_node = Node(data)
        next_node.next = self.node
        self.node = next_node

    def print_list(self):
        temp = self.node
        while (temp):
            yield temp.data
            temp = temp.next


ll = LinkedList()
ll.add_next_node(1)
ll.add_next_node(2)
ll.add_next_node(3)
ll.add_next_node(4)
for x in ll.print_list():
    print (x)

4
3
2
1
```